# Is fractional Laplacian invariant under rotation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, linear-pde

If $\Delta u=0$, then $\Delta u(Ox)=0$, where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix. From here, do we know whether fractional Laplacian is invariant under rotation? We use the usual definition of fractional laplacian of Fourier multiplier.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, it is.** The fractional Laplacian of a rotated function is the rotation of the fractional Laplacian of the function.

For $\alpha>-n$, and $\varphi\in\mathscr S_n$, 
$((-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}\varphi)^\wedge(\xi)=(4\pi^2|\xi|^2)^{\alpha/2}\hat{\varphi}(\xi)$ and it suffices to use the fact that the Fourier transform commutes with the orthogonal transformations:
If $\rho\in O(n)$ is an orthogonal transformation, then
$(f(\rho\,\cdot))\, \hat{}\, (\xi)= \hat{f}(\rho\xi)$.